# How can i run Mosquitto broker on an emulator of Android studio?

Tags: android, mqtt, mosquitto

- I am working on a project in which I need to connect and Android device to a PC.
- The plan is to install/run an open source MQTT broker on android device and develop the MQTT client library part.
- Currently I do not have access to the physical android tablet and need to rely on Android studio emulator for development

I saw some instruction that show how to run [Mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/blog/2011/11/android-mqtt-example-project/) on a physical android device through [termux](https://termux.com/).

- Does anyone know how to run Mosquito on an emulator? Can I test it only with a physical device?

Comment: Asking for software recommendations is explicitly off topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Also you are looking at a fork not the original project https://github.com/moquette-io/moquette/issues/338

Comment: Updated my question.
I basically wanted to get some feedbacks from people with some experience in MQTT broker embedding in Android projects!

Comment: Your 2 questions are so different they should be separate questions. (as for the second one, you build it from the source which is available)

Comment: removed the second question!

Comment: Also as mentioned in the description the Mosquette repository is accessible through BinTray website which is down.
https://github.com/moquette-io/moquette#embedding-in-other-projects

Comment: Ignore BinTray, all the code you need is on github and the readme you've just linked to even tells you how to build the tar file you are looking for.

Comment: @hardillb iw ish if you could share more guidance, i tried to build the .rar file based on following the following doc, but got some build error, reported as an issue (#605)
https://moquette-io.github.io/moquette/documentation.html#_embedding_into_other_projects

Answer (score 1):

Did you try RabbitMQ? they say it's the most widely deployed open source message broker.
They have a client that works on many platforms, lots of samples available too.
The Android Studio emulator works fine with the implementations.
https://www.rabbitmq.com/

Comment: Thanks @Sergio, i reviewed its documentation. I can see it widely supports many client libraries, but cannot find it being used as a broker.
https://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html